# What English words contain the vowel letters, a, e, i, o, and u, with fewest consonant letters?

Tags: language

What English words contain the five vowel letters, *a*, *e*, *i*, *o*, and *u*, with fewest consonant letters?

*Facetious* and *abstemious* contain the five in alphabetical order, and each contains four consonant letters: *fcts* in *facetious*, and *bstm* in *abstemious*. There are two instances of *s* in the case of *abstemious*, but we are counting each letter once, so both words achieve a consonant score of four.

We are looking for the word or words that contain all five of these vowel letters, not necessarily in alphabetical order, and perhaps repeated, and that have the lowest consonant score.

(Note: please can nobody edit to change "vowel letter" and "consonant letter" to "vowel" and "consonant". "Vowels" and "consonants" are sounds - they are classes of phonemes, not classes of written letters. Often a vowel letter does not represent a vowel. I am also aware that *y* often does represent a vowel and that *w* sometimes does.)

Comment: One day I was playing Scrabble with a friend, and she said *How interesting, I have all five vowels*, and I said jokingly *well then if you also have an S and a Q then you can play SEQUOIA*, and then *she did*.  I was vexed.

Comment: We also have "giouae", which is the sound I make when I wake up in the morning.

Comment: *Caesious* has all five vowel letters in order and only three consonant letters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_without_consonants

Comment: It's not an answer, but I like `facetious` because it's a (fairly) common word with the five vowels in order. If you like `y`, then go with `facetiously`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Iouea** (noun)
>
> 1. A taxonomic genus within the phylum Porifera — Cretaceous fossil sponges.

contains all five vowels, although it is a scientific word. As an alternative,

> **Eunoia** (noun)
>
> 1. (rhetoric) Goodwill towards an audience, either perceived or real; the perception that the speaker has the audience's interest at heart.

contains all vowels and one consonant. This is also the shortest word to contain all vowels.

As a bit of trivia, Christopher Bök's [Eunoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eunoia_(book)) is an anthology of poems, where each chapter is written using words limited to a single vowel.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I will accept, because nobody will beat this, but are there any other words that score one?

Comment: I can't seem to find eunoia in any well-known dictionary, apart from Wikitionary. Could you provide a link to something like the Oxford English Dictionary?

Comment: *Eunoia* is not in the OED.

Comment: @boboquack You might be interested to know that the [Guinness World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/shortest-word-in-the-english-language-that-contains-all-five-main-vowels/) lists eunoia as the smallest word containing all five vowels. Definitions can be found [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/eunoia), [here](http://www.definitions.net/definition/eunoia) and [here](https://www.wordnik.com/words/eunoia), although the word is not an accepted scrabble one.

Comment: you specifically ask for english, but as a gift, i will give you the french version: oiseau(bird).

Comment: I accept *eunoia* as a word loaned into English from ancient Greek - I've found some places where it has been used. Not so sure about *iouea* though. One can argue that binomial species names are coined straight into Latin and stay there.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a word I have just found in the Oxford English Dictionary that achieves a score of one:

> **mieaou**

It's a variant spelling of

> miaow.

Answer (score 7):

This problem seems familiar (not from another PSE question) and I can remember two answers that came up with a score of:

> 2 consonants

which were:

> Sequoia and miaoued

Note: the second was contentious to whether it was in fact a valid word, but the first definitely is.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this takes the fun out of the question, but it is a computational problem.   I obtained the list of words only containing alphabetic characters here (words_alpha.txt): https://github.com/dwyl/english-words.  First, find all uncapitalized words (avoiding proper names) that contain all the vowels:

```
 grep '^[a-z]' words_alpha.txt | grep a | grep e | grep i | grep o | grep u > tmp1
```

Then remove vowels and print the remaining length (number of consonants):

```
 sed 's/[aeiou]//g' tmp1 | awk '{print length($0)}' > tmp2
```

Finally, paste the counts next to the corresponding word, sort and take those with less than four consonants:

> ```
> paste tmp2 tmp1 | sort -g | awk '$1 < 3'
>
> 2  aboideau
> 2  aboiteau
> 2  adoulie
> 2  cadiueio
> 2  eucosia
> 2  eulogia
> 2  eulogiae
> 2  eunomia
> 2  eutocia
> 2  eutopia
> 2  miaoued
> 2  moineau
> 2  sequoia
> ```

So in this list, no word has less than two consonants, while twelve words have exactly two consonants.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: Duplicated consonant letters should be counted as one: `cat words_alpha.txt | grep -i 'a' | grep -i 'e' | grep -i 'i' | grep -i 'o' | grep -i 'u' | ruby -e 'ARGF.each{|w| w=w.strip.downcase; s=w.split("").sort.join; s=s.gsub(/[aeiou]/,""); s2=s; s2=s2.gsub(/(.)\1+/,"\\1"); puts "#{s2.length} #{w.length} #{w} #{s} #{s2}"}' | sort -n -r`.

Answer (score 2):

I found two words with 2 points (apart from `sequoia`):

> aurevoir attenuation

Though the first one is bending the rules a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned *CAESIOUS* in a comment as having three consonant letters, but I had missed that the score is based on *distinct* consonant letters, so it scores 2 and is worthy of elevation to an answer. It has the additional nice property of having each of the vowel letters exactly once and in order.

SOWPODS contains a further 12 words scoring two, of which 8 have been listed in previous answers, and one (*SEQUOIAS*) is a simple plural of one which has. The three additions are

- *DOULEIA* (not exactly a word of quotidian usage, at least in the circles I move in)
- *OSSUARIES* (probably the two-pointer I use second most after *ATTENUATION*)
- *AUTOCUTIE* (which I've never heard before, but apparently does see some use)

For completeness, the other two-pointers in SOWPODS are

- *ABOIDEAU*
- *ABOITEAU*
- *ATTENUATION*
- *EULOGIA(E)*
- *MIAOUED*
- *MOINEAU*
- *SEQUOIA*